# Migrate Magento 1.3/1.2 project(s) on PHP 5.2 to 5.3/5.5 platform(s) without changing theme, and keeping all existing product and customers data?

Tags: php, magento

My workplace decided to migrate all the projects to new server. Most of the projects are based on Magento 1.3 & 1.2, and existing server is PHP 5.2. The new server is going to be PHP 5.3. How I migrate all these Magento projects to new platform without changing theme and data?

Edit: And also I have migrate those into PHP version 5.5 (Another testing server)

Comment: I belive you have to upgrade magento.

Comment: Take a copy of your live installation, copy it to a local development machine, and make sure it still works on 5.3. @Unykvis indicates that you'll have to upgrade Magento - in which case obtain a new copy, install that over the top of the local installation, and then check again. Ensure everything is kept in a version control system, so you can roll back if necessary.

Comment: PHP 5.3 is now out of support. Can you bump the new server to at least 5.4? I don't know what the impact that has on Magento, but I'd be surprised if this did not work on the latest versions.

Comment: You'll need to bring it up to Magento 1.6 minimum so you can apply the PHP 5.4 patch. The time to bite the bullet and refactor any special programming to upgrade was about 2 years ago. PHP 5.3 is a dead end and you'll just have expended a lot of wasted effort making 1.3 marginally work instead of upgrading which is what really needs to be done.

Comment: @halfer : Some PHP functions has been depricated in Magento 1.3. Yes I am trying to upgrade it to runing in at least PHP 5.5 in my localhost. But unfortunetly, the new server also based on 5.3 as it is already purchased.

Comment: @FiascoLabs : If I update magento version, I have to re-develop the theme as per the new version. Is it?I was try to upgrade projects to Magento 1.4, but I has to re-make all themes. Because, file structures are different as some forums mentioned.

Comment: "the new server is already purchased" - is this a dedicated box? If so, just wipe it and put on latest Ubuntu LTS, which comes with PHP 5.5.

Comment: Duplicate of [What changes do I need to make Magento work with PHP 5.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296130/what-changes-do-i-need-to-make-magento-work-with-php-5-3) Get your development server live and start testing.

Comment: @FiascoLabs yes I also went through that question and answers but still I got some errors, and has not 100% successful outcome. Anyway I am configured it on V5.3 & 5.5 both and I will update the question and make the answer. Appretiate yours comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I feel like driving antique classic car on express-way.

Start project files & database migrates:

1. Ref: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_move.htm

Oh Got an error:

2. Error: Can’t retrieve entity config: core/store_group
   Ref: http://haizdesign.com/magento/magento-cant-retrieve-entity-config-solution/

   Download a new copy of Magento from the Magento Commerce site and unzip the file.
   Open Magento > lib > Varien and copy the Simplexml directory, then navigate through your sites on your localhost to the same location and replace the directory by pasting and overwriting.
   Clear cache (lib/var/cache & lib/var/session)

Reset admin as in reference or you can just change the admin's email in DB & recover password through admin panel

3. encrypted admin pasword with key 4030bc23jd67d6cee96600aa40d0390:LR

   Ref: http://www.atwix.com/magento/reset-admin-password-mysql/
4. Solutions for depricated functions:

Ref: http://www.geekieblog.com/2011/03/magento-1-3-x-environment-won%E2%80%99t-run-on-php-5-3/

Ref: [What changes do I need to make Magento work with PHP 5.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296130/what-changes-do-i-need-to-make-magento-work-with-php-5-3)

```
    File: lib/Varien/Object.php, and do the following change: L: 484

    public function ___toString(array $arrAttributes = array(), $valueSeparator=’,’)
    >>>
    public function __invoke(array $arrAttributes = array(), $valueSeparator=’,’)

    File: app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Request\Http.php and change: L:199
    $host = split(‘:’, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    >>>
    $host = explode(‘:’, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

    File: app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Sortby.php and change: L:54, 88
    $object->setData($attributeCode, split(‘,’, $data));
    >>>
    $object->setData($attributeCode, explode(‘,’, $data));

    File: app\code\core\Mage\Admin\Model\User.php and change: L:360
    $nodePath = ‘adminhtml/menu/’ . join(‘/children/’, split(‘/’, $startupPage)) . ‘/action’;
    >>>
    $nodePath = ‘adminhtml/menu/’ . join(‘/children/’, explode(‘/’, $startupPage)) . ‘/action’;

    File: app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Price.php
    __toString >>> __invoke

    File: lib/Varien/Pear.php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    >>>
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);

    File: downloader/Maged/Pear.php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    >>>
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

In Magento V1.2 : For correct the issue of return error: 'Can not add item to shopping cart' Function split() is deprecated in

```
File: \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Abstract.php on line 478
$optionIds = split(',', $optionIds->getValue()); 
>>> 
$optionIds = explode(',', $optionIds->getValue());
And
foreach(split(',', $optionValue) as $value) { 
>>> 
foreach(explode(',', $optionValue) as $value) {
```

5. Correct the Page not found errors
       [Magento site showing "not found" on clicking page link after migration the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800609/magento-site-showing-not-found-on-clicking-page-link-after-migration-the-serve)

   ```
   Add .htaccess file with :
   RewriteEngine on 
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+)(?<!\.php)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
   ```

You can use theme as it is. Site will be up & run as it is.
Enjoy your drive :-)